# How to execute JavaScript writen in one page from another page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do I execute [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) written in one aspx page from another aspx page?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do that. If both pages are from same domain and you opened the first one from second page then... no you still can't execute javascript - may be you can access the DOM using `document.referer`

Comment: Please be more specific.  Do you want to:

Have a script from page A modify page B?
Have a script from page A borrow a function or two from page B to do work in page A?
Something else?

The only way to do anything like either of the above is, as Amarghosh said, if you have opened page B from page A (or vice versa).  Then there are certain things you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this. Instead of writing your JavaScript to a page, write it to a .js file (i.e.: script.js) and then reference the .js file with a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

I'm not sure why you're asking this, but if your motivation is just to reuse the JavaScript code, then you can actually factor the code out into a separate .js file and call it from different pages by doing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_javascript_file.js"></script>
```

in those pages.

Comment: Thnks for reply
     The thing is a have a page A.aspx there is script in that 
     which will create a tab . from A i m opening another page
     B.aspx .
       what i want is when i click  a button in B.aspx .The script 
     in A.aspx should execute . or else the link in A.aspx which
     call that script should execute ...

Comment: hmm. Question is, that script in A.aspx, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `window.open` to open a new window, you can use the `window.opener` object to get a reference to the parent object from the new window and `window.open` itself will return a reference to the open page.  Example:

Page A:

```
var newWin = window.open("pageB.aspx");  // ref to pageB is stored in var newWin
newWin.onload = function () 
{
    newWin.helloB();
}
function helloA()
{
    // Run the alert method inside the new window
    newWin.alert("Hello from page A!");
}
```

page B:

```
var opener = window.opener; // Ref to pageA is stored in var opener
opener.helloA(); // call to opener's helloA function
function helloB()
{
    // Run the alert method inside the opener window
    opener.alert("Hello from page B!");
}

// We can do the same thing in an event that occurs on this page
var btn = document.getElementById("pageBButton");
btn.onclick = function ()
{
    window.opener.helloA();
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but as stated in other posts, both pages have to be on the same domain for this to work.

Comment: @SerjSagan: well, yeah, but that pretty much goes without saying ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In one page open the other page in a hidden IFrame and execute the javascript code in the hidden iframe as document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();

Note: Both the pages should be served from the same domain otherwise there will be XSS issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only when there is a parent-child relationship between pages. For example, if A.aspx is your parent page and you open page B.aspx using javascript **window.open()**, then B.aspx will be the child page. Then you can call A.aspx javascript function from B.aspx using **window.opener** instead of ***window.parent*** which I posted earlier.

Thanks.

Comment: `window.parent` is for accessing the parent from a frame.  `window.opener` is what you need.