# how to execute javascript of one page on click in another page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The thing is I have a page A.aspx there is script in that which will create a tab. from A I'm opening another page B.aspx .

What I want is when I click a button in B.aspx . The script in A.aspx should execute . or else the link in A.aspx which call that script should execute ..

Comment: huh? Is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: Why are you keep posting the same question over and over again? The first one was 20hours ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206376/how-to-call-script-of-one-aspx-page-from-another-aspx-page), then 1hour ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212151/how-to-execute-javascript-writen-in-one-page-from-another-page) and now again! Please read the FAQ for cases that you don't get the answer you were looking for (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: He's having a *lot* of trouble stating the question clearly. I think he's just trying to say "how can I have page A redirect to page B and automatically execute function C?" I think.

Answer (score 1):

you should not do this. It is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the solution for your question. You can issue a Server.Transfer to Page A from Page B and pass a context variable also. Check this context variable and then in the Page_Load event you can call the javascript function by using

**[ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx#javawasp2_topic6)**

Answer (score 0):

if the calling window opened the called window just use the handle returned from the window.open. otherwise no dice.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a link to open the new window with a call to the `window.open()` function, passing it a URL and a target.  Pass it `'_blank'` to inform the browser to use a new window:

Add this link within **A.aspx**:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('B.html', '_blank'); return false;">
    New window
</a>
```

Second, you'll also need a reference to the new window's `opener`, which is the window which created the new window:

Add this code within **B.aspx** (please replace `FUNCTION_NAME()` with your function identifier) to call your parent window's function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.FUNCTION_NAME(); // Call FUNCTION_NAME() within A.aspx.
</script>
```

You can also access `window.opener.document` to access the original window's DOM.

More information is available here:

[Documentation for window.open() function](http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

[DOcumentation for window.opener object](http://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)